# HTML Email Table Alignment with Background Image

Tags: html, email

I have created an html email and need the image "clipboard3.png" to display in the background of the image, all table content should then sit on top of the image.  Now, without the image, the table content aligns to center but when I add the image in to the body, the table and it's content are all pushed to the left.

How can I resolve this issue?  I have tried to "align: center" etc on all tables but nothing seems to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Email Template - Classic</title>
<style type="text/css">
a:hover { text-decoration: underline !important; }

</style>
</head>

<body marginheight="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" style="background:url(clipboard3.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; height:100px; width: 684px;">
<!--100% body table-->
<table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="margin: 0px auto";>
 <tr>
   <td align="center">
  <!--top links-->
  <table  width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center";>
  <tr>
      <td valign="middle" align="center" height="45">
      <p style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 24px; font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; color: #b0a08b; margin: 0px;">
      Is this email not displaying correctly? <webversion style="color: #c88b04; text-decoration: none;" href="#">Try the web version.</webversion></p></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <!--header-->
 <table style="background-color: #fffdf9;" width="684" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
 <tr>
  <td>
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
      <td valign="top" width="173">
      <!--ribbon-->
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
      <td height="120" width="45"></td>
        <td background="#c88b04" valign="top" bgcolor="" height="120" width="80"><img src="dateRibbon2.png" width="81" height="121">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
      <td valign="bottom" align="center" height="35">
      <p style="font-size: 14px; font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; color: #ffffff; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">ISSUE</p>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="center">
      <p style="font-size: 36px; font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; color: #ffffff; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #333;">31</p>
      </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
      </td>
  </tr>
  </table><!--ribbon-->
      </td>
      <td valign="middle" width="493"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
              <td height="60">

              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>
              <h1 style="color: #333; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; font-weight: normal; font-size: 48px; font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif">FirstPoint USA <em>Newsletter</em></h1>
              </td>
              <td><img src="FPFinger.png" width="102" height="186"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td height="40">
              </td>
          </tr>
      </table>
      <!--date-->
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
     </table>

      </td>
    </tr>
    </table><!--/date-->
      </td>
      <td width="18"></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
   </td>
   </tr>
  </table><!--/header-->
  <!--email container-->
  <table bgcolor="#fffdf9" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="30" width="684">
  <tr>
  <td >
  <!--email content-->
  <table cellspacing="0" border="0" id="email-content" cellpadding="0" width="624">
  <tr>
  <td>
  <!--section 1-->
  <table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
  <td valign="top" align="center">

  <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="image dsc" style="border: solid 1px #FFF; box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px #333; -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px #333; -khtml-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px #333; -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px #333;" width="622" />
  <!--line break-->
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
      <td valign="bottom" height="50"><img src="lineBreak.png" width="600" height="1"></td>
  </tr>
  </table><!--/line break-->
  <h1 style="font-size: 36px; font-weight: normal; color: #333333; font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px;">Lorem ipsum <em>dolor sit amet</em></h1>
  <p style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 22px; font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; color: #333; margin: 0px;">Consectetur adipiscing elit. <a style="color: #bc1f31; text-decoration: none;" href="#">Phasellus</a> a ipsum a risus volutpat placerat in nec mauris. Fusce sit amet enim erat, in sagittis arcu. <a style="color: #bc1f31; text-decoration: none;" href="#">Aliquam dolor dolor</a>, semper id tempor et, varius pulvinar tellus. Maurtis commodo urna at dui bibendum quis euismod velit egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et.</p>
  </td>
   </tr>
  </table><!--/section 1-->
  <!--line break-->
  <table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
  <td height="72"><img src="lineBreak.png" width="600" height="1"></td>
  </tr>
 </table><!--/line break-->
  <!--section 2-->
  <table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
   <tr>
  <td>
  <table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="8" width="100%" style="margin-top: 10px;">
    <tr>
  <td valign="top"><p style="font-size: 17px; line-height: 22px; font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; color: #333; margin: 0px;"><img src="images/img2.jpg" height="108" alt="img2" style="border: solid 1px #FFF; box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px #333; -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px #333; -khtml-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px #333; -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px #333;" width="138" /></p>
  <p style="color: #333333; font-size: 18px; font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; margin: 12px 0px; font-weight: bold;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  <p style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px; font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; color: #333; margin: 0px;">Consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus a ipsum a risus volutpat placerat in nec mauris. Fusce sit</p>
   </td>

  <td valign="top"><p style="font-size: 17px; line-height: 22px; font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; color: #333; margin: 0px;"><img src="images/img3.jpg" height="108" alt="img3" style="border: solid 1px #FFF; box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px #333; -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px #333; -khtml-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px #333; -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px #333;" width="138" /></p>
   <p style="font-size: 18px; font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; color: #333333; margin: 12px 0px; font-weight: bold;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  <p style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px; font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; color: #333; margin: 0px;">Consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus a ipsum a risus volutpat placerat in nec mauris. Fusce sit</p>
  </td>

  <td valign="top"><p style="font-size: 17px; line-height: 22px; font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; color: #333; margin: 0px;"><img src="images/img4.jpg" height="108" alt="img4" style="border: solid 1px #FFF; box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px #333; -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px #333; -khtml-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px #333; -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px #333;" width="138" /></p>
   <p style="font-size: 18px; font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; color: #333333; margin: 12px 0px; font-weight: bold;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
   <p style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px; font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; color: #333; margin: 0px;">Consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus a ipsum a risus volutpat placerat in nec mauris. Fusce sit</p>
  </td>

  <td valign="top"><p style="font-size: 17px; line-height: 22px; font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; color: #333; margin: 0px;"><img src="images/img5.jpg" height="108" alt="img5" style="border: solid 1px #FFF; box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px #333; -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px #333; -khtml-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px #333; -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px #333;" width="138" /></p>
   <p style="font-size: 18px; font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; color: #333333; margin: 12px 0px; font-weight: bold;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  <p style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px; font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; color: #333; margin: 0px;">Consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus a ipsum a risus volutpat placerat in nec mauris. Fusce sit</p>
    </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   </td>
   </tr>
   </table><!--/section 2-->
  <!--section 3-->
  <table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
  <td>
 <!--line break--><!--/line break--><!--line break--><!--/line break-->
 <table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
<tr>
</tr>
 </table>
  <!--line break--><!--/line break--><!--line break--><!--/line break-->
  </td>
 </tr>
 </table><!--/section 3-->
  </td>
  </tr>
 </table><!--/email content-->
  </td>
  </tr>
 </table><!--/email container-->
 <!--footer-->
  <table width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="30" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
  <td valign="top">
  <p style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 24px; font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; color: #b0a08b; margin: 0px;">
  You’re receiving this newsletter because you’ve subscribed to our newsletter<br> 
  Not interested anymore? <unsubscribe style="color: #bc1f31; text-decoration: none;" href="#">Unsubscribe instantly.</unsubscribe></p>
  </td>
  <td valign="top"><p style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 24px; font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; color: #b0a08b; margin: 0px;">145 North Street, Glasgow, G*****</p></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
  <td height="30"></td>
  <td height="30"></td>
  </tr>
  </table><!--/footer-->
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table><!--/100% body table-->
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: You are nesting `<\table>` tags in a really unusual way.  You should be using `rowspan` and `colspan` rather than nesting tables this way.

Comment: background-images, believe it or not, are not supported in Outlook 2010 and 2007...

Comment: One other comment; you are using tables for formatting, not for tabular data.  Rather than using table cells, you should use `div` and `span`, with the appropriate CSS for alignment.  This is best practices.

Comment: To follow up on danwellman's comment, check out http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ for CSS support.

You may want to take a look at the HTML Email Boilerplate. It's a good starting point: http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to place cells on top of the background, you might want to define the background image as a cell. You might have to break it up into several cells to accomodate your layout, but a little slicing in Photoshop should make it pretty easy.